# Picture animated align in table cell using jQuery, CSS, HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have picture centered in table cell. Using jQuery I did animation to change size of picture when mouseover cell, but now I need to align that picture to left in a same animation.

I have this HTML code:

```
<th colspan="2" height="100%" id="PoleAlena">
    <img src="./photos/AlenaKoule.png" id="AlenaKoule" style="width:50%;height:50%;">
</th>
```

Then I have jQuery code:

```
$("#PoleAlena").hover (function() {
    $("#AlenaKoule").animate({width: "15%", height: "15%",}, 1000);
});
```

So what I need is: When mouseover table cell, piscture size will reduce and move to left top conner of same cell.

Thank you for any answer.
Regards
Libor

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept?

Answer (score 3):

Like this?, where one can use `transform` and `hover` instead of script

```css
th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: left;
}
th img {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
th:hover img {
  transform: translateX(-100%) scale(0.4) ;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" height="100%" id="PoleAlena">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200/f00" id="AlenaKoule" style="width:50%;height:50%;">
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```